# Build a UNIX make project in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, makefile, gnu-make

I have a C project with a Makefile, I want to build it on windows. I downloaded [GNU Make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) installed. And I have VS2010. The make file has UNIX commands like `cc`, `nvcc` and `g++`. I have to replace them with MS C, CUDA and C++ compilers right? What are the command line commands I have to replace them with? Is there anything I need to install? 
I want to do it without Cygwin (it's installation is taking forever), otherwise Cygwin is the fallback method.

Comment: You might have GNU compiles on your Windows machine. Have you tried `which cc`?

Comment: The situation is hard to assess without the actual makefile, but it is very likely that the makefile contains more Unix-specific functionality, like shell commands and other Unix tools that you did not mention here. As an alternative to Cygwin you could try [MSYS|MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), which is more lightweight. In any case, you will have to replace the compiler and linker commands and their parameters with the VS-versions `cl` and `link` if you want to use the VS compiler suite.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to replace any of those commands with the Windows-variant.  A working compiler will still compile source code just fine even if it isn't the defacto compiler for an operating system.

I hear ya on the Cygwin bit--you can just install a Minimal GNU environment using [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/%20MinGW) and that'll give you everything that you need to be able to the utilize the **Unix** makefile.